# Subsonic 2.2, all IDataReaders manually closed but still get Max Pool Connections with a single user?

Tags: subsonic

I have a very simple web application with 5 tables and one user.  I keep getting timeout errors stating the max pool connection has been reached.  Every opportunity to use an IDataReader the connection is manually closed.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try calling LoadAndCloseReader() instead of just Load(). The Load() method opens a DataReader internally. See also: [Is connection pooling working correctly in Subsonic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690828/is-connection-pooling-working-correctly-in-subsonic)