# What are some good ways to debug timeouts? (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, subsonic, timeout

I'm building a site that runs fine for a few hours, but then *.asmx and *.ashx calls start timing out.

The exception is: "Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached."

I'm using SubSonic as the ORM.

I suspect that the problem is based on a scheduled task that runs every few minutes and hits the database. When I look in SQL Server 2000's "Current Activity", I see there are:

- 100 processes with the status "sleeping"
- 100 locks

The 100 processes are from the Application ".Net SqlClient Data Provider" and the command is "AWAITING COMMAND".

So I'm guessing that's the issue . . but how do I troubleshoot it? Does this sound like a deadlock condition in the db? As soon as I

> c:\> iisrestart

, everything's fine (for a while).

Thanks -  I've just never encountered something like this and am not sure the best way to proceed.

Michael

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be a duplicate of this problem - [Is connection pooling working correctly in Subsonic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690828/is-connection-pooling-working-correctly-in-subsonic)

If you're loading objects with Load() instead of LoadAndCloseReader(), each connection will be left open and eventually you'll exhaust the connection pool.

Comment: Thanks, 48klocs -- I had a call to .FetchByParameter(), which generated a reader which I wasn't closing. Now that that reader's in a "using" block, it's much more stable. However, I'm still steady at 2 open connections, which I don't fully understand. Much better than 100+ connections, but I'm still trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 6):

When you call Load() on a collection it will leave the Reader open - make sure you call LoadAndCloseReader() if you want the reader to close off - or use a using block.

It helps to have some source code as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Subsonic, but maybe you are leaking database 'contexts'? I'd check that any database resource is being disposed after you're finished with it...